isofs == fat32?
Is an isofs filesystem the same as a fat32 filesystem? I created a bootable Ubuntu Live 24.04 USB drive using the Start Up Disk Creator. The File Browser shows this USB drive to have an isofs file system. I need this drive to boot on an UEFI, which requires fat32.
I cannot get my computer to boot from that USB drive. Should it?
The motherboard is an ASUS ROG Crosshair VIII Extreme. Holding down the escape key during power up does not work. Holding down the F2 key during power up does not get the UEFI configuration utility.

A lot of bootable USB/CD images just have a hacked file system that is both valid FAT32 and ISO9660, despite these being distinct file systems.
This is possible because ISO9660 data structures start at a 32kB offset. The image uses this space to place an MBR with a traditional four-entry partition table, followed by a GPT partition table, which define a partition containing a FAT32 file system that describes the files required for booting, then the ISO9660 header lists the same files again. The ISO9660 file system is not inside a partition in this arrangement, but basically serves as yet another partition table.
These images are built with special tools that can interleave the data structures so they can be interpreted as a bootable harddisk or a bootable CD-ROM by a pre-EFI BIOS, or as a valid EFI boot medium.

ISO 9660 is a specific standard.
Whilst not identical to a fat32 system (a different standard; thus they independently change), the docs do state

Mount options that are the same as for msdos and vfat partitions.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.11/filesystems/isofs.html

The uEFI standard only requires the ESP (EFI System Partition) to be a specific format; outside of the ESP there is no specific requirement in regards formatting.
